# How to navigate from page that contain a list of sections to details page that contain section details

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm

I would like to navigate from master page as shown below by clicking one an item (section), to show this section details in details page using view model.

[xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPCdh.jpg)

[View model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK6jg.jpg)

Comment: First, please do not post code or errors as images.  Second, have you read the docs on navigation?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/

Answer (score 0):

When you click the item in Collectionview, then you populate the `OnSelectionChanged` method.
You can write the method like this:

```
async void OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentSelection != null)
    {
        // Navigate to the NoteEntryPage, passing the ID as a query parameter.
        Note note = (Note)e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault();
        await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(NoteEntryPage)}?{nameof(NoteEntryPage.ItemId)}={note.ID.ToString()}");
    }
}
```

This method can pass the item number to the `NoteEntryPage`.

In the NoteEntryPage, you can write a method to get the ID, then you can use the ID to get the item you.

```
async void LoadNote(string itemId)
{
    try
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(itemId);
        // Retrieve the note and set it as the BindingContext of the page.
        Note note = await App.Database.GetNoteAsync(id);
        BindingContext = note;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to load note.");
    }
}
```

You can refer to it.